# OnTextChanged Event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview

I have a gridview which has a column of textboxes called 'Quantity'.  Now, I want to execute an event handler when the text in the column changes.

This is the code for the gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView_Products" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
        BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
        HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox_Quantity" runat="server" Width="30px" OnTextChanged="Text_ChangedEvent"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <img src="Images/<%# Eval("Image_URL") %>" width="80" height="100" alt="Image" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

        <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
            HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

This is the Text_ChangedEvent event handler:

```
protected void Text_ChangedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Validation val = new Validation();

        TextBox textbox_quantity = ((TextBox)(sender));
        GridViewRow row = ((GridViewRow)(textbox_quantity.NamingContainer));

        if (textbox_quantity.Text.Equals("0") == true)
        {
            Label_Error.Visible = true;
            Label_Error.Text = "Error Message: The quantity cannot be 0!";
        }

        else
        {
            if (val.IsNumeric(textbox_quantity.Text) == false)
            {
                Label_Error.Visible = true;
                Label_Error.Text = "Error Message: The quantity must be numeric!";
            }

            else
            {
                total = total + (Convert.ToDouble(textbox_quantity.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[5].Text));
                transaction.Add(textbox_quantity.Text);
            }
        }
    }
```

Why is the event handler not executing?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `AutoPostBack="true"` attribute on the TextBox.

Comment: I tried it.  However, I am experiencing strange behaviour.  Placing a breakpoint in the event handler shows that it still does not execute.

Answer (score 1):

The event **will** fire when you post back to the page, when something changes client side there is no way for the server to know something has changed until the results are posted back.

Comment: Yes I know.  I want it to occur at the post back.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `AutoPostBack="True"`.

[Here are some solutions.](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/436223/Asp-Net-textbox-TextChanged-event-is-not-firing)

You should consider doing validation on the client side using JavaScript.

Comment: I set it to AutoPostBack=true, however it still does not enter the event handler for some reason or another :s

Comment: it won't, because it's resides in a grid

Comment: How can I get around this problem then?  Thanks

Comment: may be it should work. i'm not sure, but try to attach that event from server side by '+= new EventHandler' on some grid event, like Row_Created or something like it

Comment: I found out why it was happenning.  It was because the gridview was being binded on every postback (facepalm).  I placed the binding in !ispostback and now everything works as it should :)